# when to use object.free and freeandnil(object);

Tags: delphi, object, free

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is preferable: Free or FreeAndNil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159376/which-is-preferable-free-or-freeandnil)

when to use free and freeandnil?

in my way, i usually use the .free when the object that created is something like "object.create;" that has no self or nil parameter. if there is, that's the time i will use the freeandnil();

am i doing it right? or it has a big deference?

Comment: Why are people writing answers when they know this is an exact duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

FreeAndNil sometimes works against you; see the article "[a case against FreeAndNil](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2010/02/05/38910)" from [Allen Bauer](http://www.linkedin.com/in/abauer) (Chief Scientist at Embarcadero) about the use of [FreeAndNil](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.FreeAndNil) and the follow up article by him titled "[a case when FreeAndNil is your enemy](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2010/02/16/38916)".

Note that FreeAndNil is not bad, but you need to know what it does to oversee its consequences.

--jeroen