# What is the alternative to FreeAndNil in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have  a doubt that whether FreeAndNil is the ideal approach to dispose an object . I have come across codes where something like

```
StringList1.Free; 
StringList1 := Nil;
```

is used. Is the above line an overkill , or is it a better way to do things ? What is the difference between the two approaches?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is preferable: Free or FreeAndNil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159376/which-is-preferable-free-or-freeandnil)

Comment: i see that there is a seperate SO discussion already on this topic. Thus , i think it is better if it is closed.

Comment: Well, that depends on what this question is. I read it as the difference between FreeAndNil and the two lines of code in this question. If that reading is correct then this is not a dupe. What is your question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Yes , you read it right. Thanks for the help. I understood the diff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strictly speaking, to dispose of an object you only need to call [`Destroy`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.Destroy). However, if the reference is `nil`, ie. has not been assigned a pointer to a valid instance of an object, this would cause an access violation, so it's recommended to call [`Free`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.Free) instead which checks first if the passed reference is nil and does nothing in that case.
[`FreeAndNil`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FreeAndNil) first assigns the passed reference to a temporary local variable, then assigns `nil` to the passed reference, then calls `Free` to dispose of the instance. The only difference between `FreeAndNil` and your sequence `obj.Free; obj := nil;` is that in the first case the passed reference will be `nil` even if the destructor raises an exception.

Comment: Note that FreeAndNil is actually NilThenFree on the inside, order might be important in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

The code in your question is probably written by someone that doesn't know about `FreeAndNil`. Or perhaps it was originally written before `FreeAndNil` was added to the RTL. If you want to nil the reference then you may as well use `FreeAndNil`. Writing it out longhand doesn't help.

The only real difference is that `FreeAndNil` will set the reference to `Nil` even if `Free` raises. But your destructors should never raise anyway so this is not that big a deal in my view.

There is a common trap with `FreeAndNil`. Because it takes an untyped parameter, you can pass it anything. For example you can pass an interface, a record etc. If you make this mistake then you usually end up with strange runtime errors.

I'm not going to get started on whether or not `FreeAndNil` is an appropriate design choice. That topic has been covered in some depth elsewhere.

Comment: +1 for trying to avoid the unavoidable general discussion about `Free` vs `FreeAndNil` :)

Comment: i didnt understand what you meant by  "If you want to nil the reference then you may as well use FreeAndNil". Also , if you have any good reference , give the link , i would like to know in depth

Comment: FreeAndNil is trivially simple. The code says it all. My point is that if you want to free and object, and nil the reference, then call FreeAndNil rather than doing it in two separate steps. I can't really say it any clearer.

Comment: @naXa: I've rolled back your edit. Code formatting is to be used only on **code**, and the mere mention of a function name in text does not make it code.

Comment: @naXa, KenWhite: I agree with naXa, highlighting function names in otherwise monotone text is only helpful.